# How do I check if an object is valid when pushed to an ArrayOf[] member in my perl Moo class?

Tags: perl, types, moo

I have created a Moo class containing an array of objects which is checked against a type using [Types::Standard](https://metacpan.org/pod/Types::Standard) and I want to verify that I'm placing the right objects into that array without hard-coding too much. Here is an example of what I have right now:

```pl
package MyClass;
use Moo;
use Types::Standard qw( ArrayRef InstanceOf );

# Initially empty array of objects
has connected => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => ArrayRef[InstanceOf['MyClass']],
    default => sub { [] }
);

# Add an object to our internal list
sub connect {
    my ( $self, $other ) = @_;
    # TODO: Check if "$other" is actually an InstanceOf['MyClass']
    # without doing "$self->connected( $self->connected )"
    push @{$self->connected}, $other;
}
```

In *connect()* I add objects to my internal array but if I understand correctly, the object is never checked against `InstanceOf['MyClass']` since I don't actually *set* the array reference again.

What would be a good way to perform this validation on each *new* object? I briefly thought about doing `$self->connected( $self->connected )` after having pushed a new item but that would have to verify *every* object.

Ideally I would not even want to know exactly what's in the ArrayRef, only that it is something that has to be checked. I took a look at _type_parameter_ in the documentation for [Type::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Type::Tiny#Type-relationship-introspection-methods) but I couldn't quite figure out how to use it in my code.

Comment: What's your end goal here? House numerous types of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer ignores Moo as you you can achieve what you have asked without using it.  This does not prevent you using it if you want to, but it's not needed to do what you are asking.

Perl itself is effectively duck-typed but *does* support bless which blesses a hash reference into a class, allowing you to attach methods to it.

In the same way that in any object oriented system classes can inherit from each other in perl you can say that any class **isa** another class.  Then your code can simply check if it has been passed a hash reference that's blessed as that class.

So if I understand your question correctly, you can ensure that you only add classes of the relevant type (blessed appropriately) to your array by ensuring that your class hierarchy stipulates the correct isa relationships and checking for that.

So if you define a base type that is the type you want to check for you can have all of your other types declare that they are that:

Possible example declaration in your base :

```perl
package MyCore;

sub new
{
my ($Class, $obj);

  $Class=shift;
  $obj= { Key => 'Value' };
  bless($obj, $Class);
  return($obj);
}
```

possible declartion in a derived type:

```perl
use MyCore;

package MyDerived;
@MyDerived::ISA=('MyCore');

sub new()
{
my ($Class, $Obj);

  $Class=shift;
  $Obj=MyCore::new();
  $Obj->{NewKey}='NewValue';
  bless($Obj, $Class);
}
```

Then when you are adding to an array:

```perl
sub connect()
{
  my ($Self, $Other);
  $Self=shift;
  $Other=($#_>=0)?shift:undef;

  if(defined($Other) && $Other->isa('MyCore'))
  {
    push(@{$Self->{Connected}}, $Other);
  }
}
```

We use this approach in a high volume webserver built on mod_perl and it is simple and easy to relate to for users of other object oriented environments.

Comment: Your check can throw an exception. It should be `if(defined(blessed($Other)) && $Other->isa('MyCore'))`. `blessed` is provided by Scalar::Util

Answer (score 4):

An answer for an old question because I've been unable to log in to StackExchange for quite a while...

```
package MyClass;
use Moo;
use Types::Standard qw( ArrayRef InstanceOf );
use Sub::HandlesVia;

has connected => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => ArrayRef[InstanceOf['MyClass']],
    default => sub { [] },
    handles_via => 'Array',
    handles => {
      'connect' => 'push',
    }
);
```

Sub::HandlesVia will automatically take care of the type check for you.

Answer (score 2):

This performs the same check:

```
use Type::Tiny::Class qw( );

my $MyClass_type = Type::Tiny::Class->new( class => 'MyClass' );

sub connect {
    my ( $self, $other ) = @_;

    $MyClass_type->check($other)
       or die "Validation error";

    push @{ $self->connected }, $other;
}
```

Looks like you you can also  use

```
if ( my $error = $MyClass_type->validate($other, '$other') ) {
   die($error);
}
```

and

```
if ( my $errors = $MyClass_type->validate_explain($other, '$other') ) {
   die(join("\n", @$errors));
}
```

`->validate` is probably the best option.

Untested.